# Having trouble with a vbscript creating a new vbscript containing a variable from the original

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a vbs that creates a new vbs file, but im having some trouble with the creation of the second file.

Earlier in the first script it asks for your desired username, which is then assigned to a variable named user.

When it creates the second script, i want the user name to display in a message saying Welcome back [insert username here]. Please input a program value.

problem is, i cant get it to place your username inside of the new scripts code.

attempt 1

```
If VTCreate1 = 6 And VTCreate2 = 7 And VTCreate3 = 7 And VTCreate4 = 7 And VTCreate5 = 7 Then
Set objFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Aeshnidae_1627374757.vbs")
objFile.WriteLine("vtcmd=inputbox(""Welcome back "")" & user & "("". Please input a program value."")")
```

attempt 1 results in the newly created script containing the following

```
vtcmd=inputbox("Welcome back ")Human(". Please input a program value.")
```

attempt 2

```
If VTCreate1 = 6 And VTCreate2 = 7 And VTCreate3 = 7 And VTCreate4 = 7 And VTCreate5 = 7 Then
Set objFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Aeshnidae_1627374757.vbs")
objFile.WriteLine("vtcmd=inputbox(""Welcome back & user & . Please input a program value."")")
```

attempt 2 results in the following

```
vtcmd=inputbox("Welcome back & user & . Please input a program value.")
```

any idea how to get the desired username properly inside of the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the final desired output line

```
vtcmd=inputbox("Welcome back xxxxxx. Please input a program value")
```

To place it inside a string variable (what we will later write) we need to quote the line and escape inner double quotes

```
"vtcmd=inputbox(""Welcome back xxxxxx. Please input a program value"")"
```

To replace the placeholder we need to cut our string

```
"vtcmd=inputbox(""Welcome back "     ". Please input a program value"")"
                   close quote ^     ^ open quote
```

And concatenate the variable with the two strings

```
"vtcmd=inputbox(""Welcome back " & user & ". Please input a program value"")"
```

So, the final code line will be

```
objFile.WriteLine "vtcmd=inputbox(""Welcome back " & user & ". Please input a program value"")"
```